# Guest user account request filenotfound VF page

Tags: force.com-sites, guest-user

I have created a Guest User Account for the fielding of Webhooks from a third party platform. I set the same system up in a sandbox, and it worked well.
When I set up the same Site in production, I'm seeing constant requests for `fileNotFound`.

Below are some of the lines from the debug log when monitoring the Site Guest User:

```
User        Request Type Application Operation        Status Duration (ms) Log Size (bytes)**
    
SiteGuestUserX Application  Browser /apex/FileNotFound  Success 58  1,182   12/20 18:08:28

SiteGuestUserX Application  Browser /apex/FileNotFound  Success 54  1,182   12/20 18:08:26

SiteGuestUserX Application  Browser /apex/FileNotFound  Success 63  1,182   12/20 18:08:26
```

Does anyone know the origin of these requests and how I might stop them?  The true requests come through with a request type of API and they are processed correctly.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Well, you've got guest users so your community is public-facing on the internet. This traffic could be all sorts of bots and scanners probing your site and attempting to craft URLs that don't exist and then get rerouted to your 404 page (FileNotFound). If there is a log somewhere that includes all traffic with IP addresses you will get a better sense of what's going on.